# inner join large table with small table , how to speed up

Tags: php, sql, mysql

dear php and mysql expertor
i have two table one large for posts artices 200,000records (index colume: sid) , and one small table (index colume topicid ) for topics has 20 record .. have same **topicid**

curent im using : ( it took round 0.4s)

**+do get last 50 record from table:**

SELECT sid, aid, title, time, topic, informant, ihome, alanguage, counter, type, images, chainid FROM veryzoo_stories ORDER BY sid DESC LIMIT 0,50

**+then do while loop in each records for find the maching name of topic in each post:**

while ( .. ) { 
SELECT topicname FROM veryzoo_topics WHERE topicid='$topic'"
....
}

***+Now
I going to use Inner Join for speed up process but as my test it took much longer from 1.5s up to 3.5s***

SELECT a.sid, a.aid, a.title, a.time, a.topic, a.informant, a.ihome, a.alanguage, a.counter, a.type, a.images, a.chainid, t.topicname FROM veryzoo_stories a INNER JOIN veryzoo_topics t ON a.topic = t.topicid ORDER BY sid DESC LIMIT 0,50

*It look like the inner join do all joining 200k records from two table fist then limit result at 50 .. that took long time..*

**Please help to point me right way doing this..
eg take last 50 records from table one.. then join it to table 2 .. ect**

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use inner join unless the two tables share the same primary key, or you'll get duplicate values (and of course a slower query).

Comment: nop two table dont have same p key .. the large tabe p key is: sid and small table has topicid as p key

Comment: I would use the do while. Join are hardly a way to speed up queries unless certain conditions are satisfied.

Comment: I disagree. Making 50 queries will produce a lot of overhead. With a join (or a barbarian join with WHERE), there will be only one query. JOIn statements have been made to work with relations. If the database is well designed (with indexes and relations) and use a modern engine that supports relations, the performance should be better.

Comment: Join statements work creating a cross product of records between the two tables and then selecting occurrences that satisfy certain relations, so it is essential to specify *good* relations, otherwise you'll get multiply values, or no values at all (depending on the type of join). Sorry, my answer was sort of irrelevant to the question (and also a bit inaccurate): I was not thinking about speeding up the query but obtaining the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT a.sid, a.aid, a.title, a.time, a.topic, a.informant, a.ihome, a.alanguage, a.counter, a.type, a.images, a.chainid
FROM veryzoo_stories a
ORDER BY sid DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 50
)b
INNER JOIN veryzoo_topics t ON b.topic = t.topicid
```

I made a small test and it seems to be faster. It uses a subquery (nested query) to first select the 50 records and then join.

Also make sure that veryzoo_stories.sid, veryzoo_stories.topic and veryzoo_topics.topicid are indexes (and that the relation exists if you use InnoDB). It should improve the performance.

Now it leaves the problem of the ORDER BY LIMIT. It is heavy because it orders the 200,000 records before selecting. I guess it's necessary. The indexes are very important when using ORDER BY.

Here is an article on the problem : [ORDER BY … LIMIT Performance Optimization](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/)

Comment: thanks for confirm .. look like your solution same mine.. I stick with this.. thanks very much

Comment: OK. I added a link to an interesting article on ORDER BY LIMIT performance if you're interested. Are there indexes for the columns I mentioned? Which backend are you using (InnoDB, MyISAM)? Anyway if you think that the question is answered, please choose one answer (yours or mine) as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just give test to nested query + inner join and suprised that performace increase much:  it now took only 0.22s .  Here is my query:

```
SELECT a.*, t.topicname 
FROM (SELECT sid, aid, title, TIME, topic, informant, ihome, alanguage, counter, TYPE, images, chainid 
  FROM  veryzoo_stories 
  ORDER BY sid DESC 
  LIMIT 0, 50) a 
  INNER JOIN veryzoo_topics t ON a.topic = t.topicid
```

if no more solution come up , i may use this one .. thanks for anyone look at this post

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the answer. This is exactly what I did. I thinks it's the right way to go.

Comment: Are there indexes for veryzoo_stories.sid, veryzoo_stories.topic and veryzoo_topics.topicid? This could also improve performance.